# Why do HttpClient.PostAsync and PutAsync dispose the content?

Tags: .net, idisposable, dotnet-httpclient, dispose

The behavior of the [HttpClient.PostAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138190(v=vs.118).aspx) method is to dispose of the provided [HttpContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent(v=vs.118).aspx) object.

There are many ways to get around this behavior including constructing a new `HttpContent` for each call made on the client or loading the content to a stream and changing the pointer.

I'm wondering **why** invoking this method automatically invokes the disposal of its `IDisposable` parameters? As far as I'm aware this is not a common behavior in .NET

It's also worth noting that this behavior is observed in `PUT` requests as well, which are idempotent, so the premise that this behavior is to prevent the information from being sent again doesn't seem correct.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/14612

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I couldn't immediately find the implementation on referencesource but the WCF source contains it as well. The method you're looking for is [`DisposeRequestContent(HttpRequestMessage)`](http://wcf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/417c9a96fc24#WCFWebApi%2FHttp%2FSrc%2FMicrosoft.Net.Http%2FHttpClient.cs) and the accompanying comment says this:

> When a request completes, `HttpClient` disposes the request content so the user doesn't have to. 
>   This also ensures that a `HttpContent` object is only sent once using `HttpClient` (similar to `HttpRequestMessages` that can also be sent only once).

```
HttpContent content = request.Content;
if (content != null)
{
    content.Dispose();
}
```

Basically it's a safeguard to make sure you don't send the same response twice which they consider a bad/uncommon/discouraged use case.

Comment: I can *maybe* understand this behavior for `POST` calls, but the same behavior is observed for `PUT` requests which are idempotent; so the explanation about only sending it once doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Matthew  It also doesn't make sense to dispose if you call LoadIntoBufferAsync on the HttpContent.  When I create derived HttpContent classes, I will often ensure that the Dispose method does nothing destructive so that I can safely reuse the content.  Dispose originally was only supposed to be used for cleaning up unmanaged resources. I really don't like the fact that it is now being used for arbitrary cleanup.

Comment: Here's the only documentation I could find for this "convenience" feature, though I fail to see how it is convenient to do this and as far as I can tell not even officially document the behavior anywhere: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/14612

Comment: P.S. can you tell I wasted 4 hours on this?

Comment: I just ran into this behavior while unit testing a multi-target project. Interestingly I do not get object disposed exceptions when the tests run against NetCore. I guess they fixed it?

Comment: Yes, they did: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/19082

Comment: I know where this behavior mentioned by the OP is useful and justified. When I call a method on HttpClient, e.g. PostAsync, and I am uploading a file using StreamContent object, I require that the latter's Dispose method be called by PostAsnyc. This will remove the burden from me in keeping a reference on the StreamContent object and calling it's Dispose method once the results of the PostAsnyc call is available.